# Apache 2.4 - How to deny access to DocumentRoot but allow 'trailing slash' access to DirectoryIndex file

Tags: apache, apache2.4

In my Apache 2.4 VirtualHost configuration, I'd like to - by default - deny access to everything in the `DocumentRoot` that I do not enable explicitly. To that end, I have written:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory "/var/www">
  Require all denied 
  <Files "index.html">
    Require all granted
  </Files>
</Directory>
```

This enables direct access to `http://myserver.example/index.html`, but results in a `403` response for indirect access to `http://myserver.example/`.

How can I correct this behaviour?

Comment: It seems to behave exactly as you want: you did not explicitly allow `/`, so it is forbidden

Comment: @Dusan : Thanks, that set me on the right track, see answer! The reasons are still a little unclear to me, but I at least found a practical solution.

Answer (score 1):

Following the hint that I "did not explicitly allow `/`", resulting in it being forbidden set me on the right track to solve this.
Adding a `LocationMatch` directive that deals with the trailing slash exclusively results in the desired behaviour:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory "/var/www/">
  Require all denied
  <Files "index.html">
    Require all granted
  </Files>
</Directory>

# Regex anchored at string beginning and end
# -> only matches "/"
<LocationMatch "^/$">
  Require all granted
</LocationMatch>
```

Note that adding a `<Files "/">` directive does not work, probably because the accessed resource is not really a file.
Neither is `<Location />` the right thing, because it would be applied to the entire VirtualHost.